# Azure SQL db issue...NullReference Exception

Tags: azure

We have deployed our .NET solution project on Azure. After deployment we are testing application it is working properly. But after some hours or next day we are testing same application link at that time we are getting error on the screen.

We tried to test using same Azure database in local environment where this application is working absolutely fine. Also we set for some hours this application as an idle position and then also its working properly.

We tried to track the error but we failed to get it. Please refer following error screen image for more reference.

Also we checked db connection functionality in the code and also tried to use Retrypolicy under web role but no luck for us. Error message:

> Message:Execution of the command requires an open and available
>   connection. The connection's current state is broken., StatusCode:200

If anyone have solution on this type of error or suggestions please let us know. Thanks in advance.

https://XYZ.com?trxCode={Message:Execution%20of%20the%20command%20requires%20an%20open%20and%20available%20connection.%20The%20connection's%20current%20state%20is%20broken.,StatusCode:200}

Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

NullReferenceException
 thrown in Transaction TaxiFareDetail

Error Details:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The title of your question mentions the NullReference exception, whereas this exception is never mentioned in text. The text, however, references an image that is missing either. Could you please correct the question to match the title against the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you disposing of your connections after using them? The best way to do this is to wrap your connections in a using block. This will ensure that unused connections are returned to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your error message, you SQL Azure connection just times out.

Did you try to check for the connection status before sending any command and manually re-establish connection if it is not opened and active? [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/11/10011247.aspx) is some code you might reuse as the starting point for your logic.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the reply, actually we are using .NET Entity framework for database and we had already set connection retry policy. We are going through your code link let see how much it will help us.